# Error Trigger. The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do an UPDATE using a TRIGGER.

I have 2 Databases (eBob and Sbmx_taslado) in which they share information, material and density.

What I'm trying to make is that when you change the density of a material (database Sbmx_traslado) this is updated (eBob database).

The problem is that the table is updated where the material can be repeated the same in different container, which sends me the following error:

(Excuse my English, use google)

[image]

```
Use Sbmx_traslado
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DensidadMaterial2
ON  [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel]
SET [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[ProductDensityWeight] = [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores].[Densidad]
FROM [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores]
WHERE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[Contents] = [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores].[Ingrediente]
```

Comment: Here is a start: That error means that you are using an alias in your statement that hasnt been declared.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Write the error (in english) in text.

Comment: how are the 2 tables connected right now.

Comment: ok sorry, for the screen image.

Comment: databases are in the same instance

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a table in the WHERE clause that is not in the FROM.  Try this.

```
Use Sbmx_traslado
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DensidadMaterial2
ON  [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel]
SET [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[ProductDensityWeight] = [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores].[Densidad]
FROM [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel]
JOIN [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores] ON [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[Contents] = [Sbmx_traslado].[dbo].[Sbmx_Contenedores].[Ingrediente]
```

Comment: I get the same problem:
the updated values alter multiple rows